# How to send a HTTP Header request rather than HTTP URL in Python

Tags: python, django, http, oauth, header

I'm doing Oauth, and Linkedin needs me to send a "header" request instead of URL request (I have no idea what that means).

This is what someone says on Google:

> If the library you are using isn't
>   using HTTP headers for the
>   authorization, you're not going to be
>   able to access protected resources.
>   Most OAuth libraries have an option
>   that you can specify that will force
>   it to use the header-based
>   authorization.

Anyway, I specified it to headers! I know how to change it to headers. The only problem is...I don't know how to **REQUEST** stuff using the header method.

**Before, without the header method:**

```
url = oauth_request.to_url()
connection.request(oauth_request.http_method,url)
response = connection.getresponse()
s = response.read()
```

**Now:**

```
url = oauth_request.to_header()
connection.request(oauth_request.http_method,url)
response = connection.getresponse()
s = response.read()
```

But when I run it, I get this weird traceback.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py" in request
  874.             self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py" in _send_request
  891.         self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py" in putrequest
  807.                 if url.startswith('http'):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /g/
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: I solved it. I just put a 3rd argument , which is headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about this particular oauth library you are using, so I can't comment on that.

But,

- It can be clearly identified from the traceback, that `oauth_request.to_header()` returns a dictionary and not a string, that httplib.py expects.
- The way to set authentication credentials in http headers is as follows:

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720867/http-authentication-in-python)

```
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
top_level_url = "http://example.com/"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, 'user', 'password')
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler, handler)
request = urllib2.Request(url)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your connection.request method can take in HTTP headers:

connection.request(method, url, body = body, headers={'Authorization':header})

For OAuth, there are a bunch of fields that 'header' has:

> OAuth realm="http://api.linkedin.com", oauth_consumer_key="##########", oauth_nonce="############", oauth_signature="########", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="#########", oauth_token="#########", oauth_version="1.0"

All the #### are things you need to have or generate.